# Aggregate events at different interval in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have this table that tracks budget usage of an advertising campaign. It has those fields:

- AdvertiserID
- Budget Scope ID: It's the campaign ID
- Budget: Budget of the campaign (es. 100$/day) and it can change during the day
- Percentage: Percentage of the budget spent today (from 00:00 to 23:59)
- Usage_updated_timestamp: Timestamp event

Now I want to plot a sawtooth chart of the total cost (budget*percentage/100) aggregating by AdvertiserId and summing the cost for all campaigns.
I expect the cost to go up during the day and fall to 0 at midnight because percentage is 0.

The problem is that I do not have records all at the same timestamp but they are randomly updated during the day. So I tried with this query:

```
SELECT
 advertiser_id,
 usage_updated_timestamp,
 SUM(budget*budget_usage_percentage/100) AS cost
FROM budget_usages
GROUP BY 1,2
```

But as you can see the cost decrease during the day because for the same timestamp I have a record for one campaign and not for the other. I cannot use date_trunc('hour', timestamp) because they are random. The only thing I know is that the percentage resets to 0 at midnight.
My idea is that I need to consider, for each minute, the last updated value for each existing campaign (budget_scope_id) and sum it.

FIDDLE: https://dbfiddle.uk/sTxfucZ1

My desidered results is:

| Timestamp | Cost | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 7:00 | 250 | 1000 * 0.25 |
| 2024-01-01 8:00 | 1600 | 3000 * 0,45 + 1000 * 0,25 |
| 2024-01-01 10:00 | 1650 | 3000 * 0.45 + 1000 * 0.30 |

Comment: So far, I have https://dbfiddle.uk/fs8NUW1h: the query is aggregating costs across the timestamps correctly but does not reset at midnight (as opposed to the expected sawtooth pattern, where costs reset to 0 at midnight). Would a procedural approach (e.g., PL/pgSQL function) be acceptable? One that would iterate through each hour, fetching the last known values for each campaign and summing them up until midnight, where the sum is then reset.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the full desired result, and ensure the accuracy of the `Cost` ? It appears that the `Cost` does not align with the information in the `Notes`.

Comment: Please show us your desired results that match the sample data that you provided in the fiddle. Does you desired result really has only three rows? Please explain how you got those results. Cost = 300 and Notes = 3000 * 0.45 + 1000 * 0.30 do not make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My idea is that I need to consider, for each minute, the last updated value for each existing campaign (budget_scope_id) and sum it.

Yes, except that you cannot just sum the values since they are already cumulated (per day). So you would first need to get the delta of each update, per campaign (and considering the day). This is possible using the `LAG` window function. Then afterwards you can sum these deltas, across campaigns, with a window function that aggregates per day. Throw in some zero values for restarting at each midnight and you get

```sql
WITH expenses as (
  SELECT
    advertiser_id,
    marketplace_id,
    usage_updated_timestamp,
    ( budget * budget_usage_percentage / 100. 
    - LAG(budget * budget_usage_percentage / 100, 1, 0) OVER w1
    ) AS delta
  FROM budget_usages
  WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY advertiser_id, 
                             marketplace_id, 
                             budget_scope_id, 
                             date_trunc('day', usage_updated_timestamp) 
                ORDER BY usage_updated_timestamp)
UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT
    advertiser_id,
    marketplace_id,
    date_trunc('day', usage_updated_timestamp),
    0 AS delta
  FROM budget_usages
)
SELECT
  advertiser_id,
  marketplace_id,
  usage_updated_timestamp AS timestamp,
  SUM(delta) OVER w2 AS cost
FROM expenses
WINDOW w2 AS (PARTITION BY advertiser_id, 
                           marketplace_id, 
                           date_trunc('day', usage_updated_timestamp) 
              ORDER BY usage_updated_timestamp)
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

<sup>([updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kTdj7Y1r))</sup>

Comment: @SalmanA How so? *07:00 - `250`, 08:00 - `1600`, 10:00 - `1650`* appears to be exactly the OP's desired result.

Comment: Oh wait another thanks to @Zegarek for updating the fiddle with the new sample data

Comment: Thank you. I tried both answers, then I picked up this because it was easy to understand, maintain and customize. I haven't tested which one is most efficient.

Comment: @sparkle You can be sure this one is. Scalar/lateral subqueriesare are typically rather expensive, and this task is pretty much exactly what window functions are for. Main advantage of the subqueries is that they *might* be a bit easier to "think in", if you can afford the cost in performance (and are not yet used to window functions). There are things they can do window functions can't, but that's not one of them.

Comment: Following up on this: the lateral subquery approach takes twice as long on half the sample set (2s on 50k rows [demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/puswl21o)) when compared to a reference run using window function approach (1s on 100k rows [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/pW8DmMpb)). Those are the versions with midnights added and only current total "Cost" calculated for each row, to make it apples-to-apples.

Answer (score 3):

[`LATERAL` subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) and [`window functions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78054343/5298879) let you define how far back you want to reach, then *look back* from a row: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8FvFCx1E)

```sql
select *, current_total_spending / current_total_budget * 100 as "% spent"
from budget_usages as "then",
lateral
( select sum(budget)::float   as current_total_budget,
         sum(spending)::float as current_total_spending
  from( select distinct on(advertiser_id,budget_scope_id)
               budget,
               budget_usage_percentage*budget/100. spending
        from budget_usages as "by_then"
        where "by_then".usage_updated_timestamp
               <="then".usage_updated_timestamp
          and("by_then".usage_updated_timestamp::date,
              "by_then".advertiser_id)    
              = ("then".usage_updated_timestamp::date,
                 "then".advertiser_id)
        order by advertiser_id,
                 budget_scope_id, 
                 usage_updated_timestamp desc)_)_
order by usage_updated_timestamp;
```

| Timestamp | Cost | Notes | scope_id | budget | % spent | total | total % spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 07:00 | 250 | 1000*0.25 | 1 | 1000.00 | 25.00 | 1000 | 25.00 |
| 2024-01-01 08:00 | 1600 | 1000*0.25+3000*0.45 | 2 | 3000.00 | 45.00 | 4000 | 40.00 |
| 2024-01-01 10:00 | 1650 | 1000*0.3+3000*0.45 | 1 | 1000.00 | 30.00 | 4000 | 41.25 |
| 2024-01-01 12:00 | 2100 | 1000*0.3+3000*0.6 | 2 | 3000.00 | 60.00 | 4000 | 52.50 |
| 2024-01-01 15:00 | 3300 | 1000*0.3+3000*1 | 2 | 3000.00 | 100.00 | 4000 | 82.50 |
| 2024-01-01 16:00 | 3300 | 1000*0.3+6000*0.5 | 2 | 6000.00 | 50.00 | 7000 | 47.14 |
| 2024-01-01 23:00 | 6300 | 1000*0.3+6000*1 | 2 | 6000.00 | 100.00 | 7000 | 90.00 |
| 2024-01-02 07:00 | 100 | 1000*0.1 | 1 | 1000.00 | 10.00 | 1000 | 10.00 |
| 2024-01-02 08:00 | 700 | 1000*0.1+6000*0.1 | 2 | 6000.00 | 10.00 | 7000 | 10.00 |

This is driven by the distribution of your entries. If you prefer evenly-spaced hourly reporting, you can [instead correlate with `distinct advertiser_id, generate_series()`](https://dbfiddle.uk/caaAOtEp).

You don't need to `round()` to get rid of trailing zeroes if you instead cast to `::float` - their default output format rounds those off. I'm showing rounded to 2 decimal places to simplify the demo.

The [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) picks the latest budgets and spendings for each `advertiser_id` and `budget_scope_id` for each row you're looking back from.

Comment: Ah, nice approach! I thought of this when trying generate the `notes` that the OP showed, which is [easy to add here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uxI3fOsd). I would have attempted to use the `last_value` window function instead of `distinct on`+`order by`, but didn't find the time to actually write it up.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I like two things about it: one is that it's simple to follow intuitively, because it's literally just taking each row and looking back from it, the other that it was easier to [plug `generate_series()` into it](https://dbfiddle.uk/g94HEnEd). Initially I actually went with window functions *because that'll just perform better*, but since you and VonC were already on it, I figured I'd just [add](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78054343/2) what more I had with those to your already posted answer and keep mine focused on a "plain" lateral subquery.

Comment: Thank you. How could I add all zeros at midnight as in @Bergi answer ?

Comment: @sparkle If you want evenly-spaced blocks, you can use [`generate_series`](https://dbfiddle.uk/g94HEnEd). If you only want to add "filler records" with zeroes every day at midnight for each `advertiser_id`, you can combine that with [`union select distinct`](https://dbfiddle.uk/lZXZ8UE2).

Comment: @sparkle See [the dbfiddle from my first comment](https://dbfiddle.uk/uxI3fOsd) where I did add that in the last snippet