# Create view with join depending on table of another join

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database, postgrest

My tables:

```sql
create table Article (
  ID int generated by default as identity primary key, 
  Name text);
create table Client (
  ID int generated by default as identity primary key, 
  Name text);
create table Invoice (
  ID int generated by default as identity primary key, 
  Date date, 
  Client int references client(id));
create table InvoicePosition (
  ID int generated by default as identity primary key, 
  Invoice int references invoice(id), 
  Article int references article(id), 
  Quantity numeric, 
  Price numeric,
  constraint each_invoice_can_only_contain_one_invoiceposition_for_each_article
    unique (Invoice,Article));
```

Sample data:

```sql
insert into article(id,name) values
  (1,'article1'),
  (2,'article2'),
  (3,'article3');
insert into client(id,name) values
  (1,'client1'),
  (2,'client2'),
  (3,'client3');
insert into invoice(id,date,client) values
  (1,'yesterday',1),    -- Invoice by Client 1
  (2,'today',1),        -- Invoice by Client 1
  (3,'tomorrow',1),     -- Invoice by Client 1
  (4,'yesterday', 2);   -- Invoice by Client 2
insert into InvoicePosition values
  (1,1,1,11.0,77.0),    -- Invoice from yesterday by client 1 with article 1
  (2,1,2,22.0,88.0),    -- Invoice from yesterday by client 1 with article 2
  (3,1,3,33.0,99.0),    -- Invoice from yesterday by client 1 with article 3
  (4,2,1,12.0,78.0),    -- Invoice from today by client 1 with article 1
  (5,2,2,23.0,89.0),    -- Invoice from today by client 1 with article 2
  (6,4,1,34.0,100.0);   -- Invoice from yesterday by client 2 with article 1
```

Now I would like to select an `InvoicePosition` with details of the previous `InvoicePosition` (same client, same article).
Basically:

- PreviousInvoicePosition.Article = InvoicePosition.Article
- PreviousInvoicePosition.Invoice.Client = InvoicePosition.Invoice.Client
- PreviousInvoicePosition.Invoice.Date < InvoicePosition.Invoice.Date
- Select only the first `PreviousInvoicePosition`, ordered by `Date` descending.

Ideally this should be created as a view so I can then select all `InvoicePosition`s (including the `PreviousInvoicePosition`) for one invoice, using a `WHERE` clause.

Example select from created view:

```
// Invoice from today from client 1 with article 1
SELECT * FROM InvoicePosView WHERE InvoicePosId = 4
```

Expected result:

```
InvoicePosId = 4
InvoiceId = 2
ArticleID = 1
Quantity = 12.0
Price = 78.0
LastInvoicePosId = 1    // Invoice from yesterday from client 1 with article 1
```

If it matters: This tables and the view are part of a supabase project and are then queried using PostgREST.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe `lag(<detail field>) over (partition by "Article", "Client" order by "Date")` will do the job.

Comment: In your question, the word "previous" is undefined. What is the desired order?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe previous is defined as date < this invoice date and ordered by date descending. So the latest invoice before this one, which has the same client and the same article.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm never heard about that, I'll have to take a look at it. Thank you

Comment: Ok, invoices can be ordered by `date`, but not `invoiceposition`s. What is the order of two `invoiceposition`s that belong to the same `invoice`?

Comment: I edited the question to add a detail: Each `Invoice` can onlyhave one position for each `Article`. So I have to find the latest invoice, dated before this one, which contains the article of this position. The positions don't need to be ordered anymore, as they are unique in every `Invoice`.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And don't forget to show us your current code attempt.

Comment: @RobertP Given the sample structure and data, please add an expected result you want to get based on those. It does sound like you'll just need a [`lag()over w1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). Attach how far you got with your query, what you've tried and what's still missing/wrong.

Comment: @Zegarek the sample data wasn't added by me, but I'll try to update it and add the expected result. Thanks

Comment: @RobertP [I added it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78112422/3) to make your description of code, runnable code. Feel free to replace it, if you have some additional DDL details or samples for specific test cases.

Comment: I tried to add an example with expected result, I hope it is clearer now. Sometimes the question you ask seems clear to yourself (as you know what your asking) but is missing required details for others to understand it.

Comment: @RobertP Thanks, looks clear now. I think it boils down to runnable code always being clearer than a description of what it does or is supposed to do. Same with example/demonstration of behaviour, rather than a description/spec. I've [updated by answer to match](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78114681/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [`lag()over w1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).
[Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/qGI4zBWV)

```sql
create view invoices_with_previous as 
select ip.id       as "InvoicePosId",
       i.id        as "InvoiceId",
       ip.article  as "ArticleID",
       ip.quantity as "Quantity",
       ip.price    as "Price",
       lag(ip.id)over w1 as "LastInvoicePosId"
from InvoicePosition  as  ip 
  join invoice i on i.id =ip.invoice
window w1 as (partition by i.client, ip.article
              order by i.date)
order by ip.id;

select * from invoices_with_previous;
```

| InvoicePosId | InvoiceId | ArticleID | Quantity | Price | LastInvoicePosId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 11.0 | 77.0 | *null* |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 22.0 | 88.0 | *null* |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 33.0 | 99.0 | *null* |
| **4** | **2** | **1** | **12.0** | **78.0** | **1** |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 23.0 | 89.0 | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 | 34.0 | 100.0 | *null* |

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that out as soon as possible.
I'll try to summarize what this does in my understanding:
First you select the invoicepositions, joined with invoice, article, client.
Then you partition the result by client and article, the rows within a partition are ordered by the invoice date (should `order by i.date`, right?). The you use "lag" function to include the previous row into the end result.
Thank you again! I was thinking that I am just missing something and this is possible with some simple joins but there are quite a few new things for me.

Comment: Your summary is exactly right. Achieving what you want is possible in a number of ways, but this one's *the proper way to do it*, the simplest and will perform the best. Same can be done with a correlated lateral subquery or a correlated scalar subquery, where you just point back from a row to where you want - in this case, another row, right before. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78040865/5298879)

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for.
Just a note: In this case the join on client and article does not seem to be necessary, the partition by  could also use ip.client instead of c.id and ip.article instead of a.id.
When I need more info about client, article etc. I could still join when selecting from this view.

Comment: @RobertP Good point, those were leftovers from the previous version where I fetched and displayed it all, based on your initial description of how these join. I added the fix here and in the demo