# Query to sum over multiple rows based on column

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with monthly amounts per ID, where in some of these months an invoice takes place.

My table looks like:

| ID | Date | Invoiced | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2023-01 | 0 | 10 |
| AAA | 2023-02 | 0 | 15 |
| AAA | 2023-03 | 1 | 15 |
| AAA | 2023-04 | 0 | 10 |
| AAA | 2023-05 | 0 | 10 |
| AAA | 2023-06 | 1 | 10 |
| BBB | 2022-05 | 0 | 40 |
| BBB | 2022-06 | 1 | 20 |
| BBB | 2022-07 | 0 | 30 |
| BBB | 2022-08 | 1 | 30 |

I need to have the rows only per ID with the invoice months, where we sum over the previous amounts since the last invoice.
What I want to have:

| ID | Date | Invoiced | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2023-03 | 1 | 40 |
| AAA | 2023-06 | 1 | 30 |
| BBB | 2022-06 | 1 | 60 |
| BBB | 2022-08 | 1 | 60 |

How this can be done in postgresql? I started with the query below, but it gives not yet what I need.

```
SELECT "ID", "Date", "Invoiced"
      , sum(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY "Invoiced" ORDER BY "Id", "Date") AS Amount
FROM   Table
```

Comment: If you switch `"Date"` to actual `date` type, you will save some space, speed up operations, then speed up more thanks to better indexing, plus avoid some anomalies caused by lexicographic sorting. Similar thing with `"Invoiced"` if you make it a `boolean`. It would also help if you don't mix case and double-quoted and unquoted identifiers. At the moment, the query wouldn't work because `"ID"` and `"Id"` are understood as two distinct fields, one of which probably doesn't exist. If it was created unquoted, it's folded to lowercase and named just `"id"`, so neither of those would be recognised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *gaps and islands* problem, you could use `SUM()` as window function in descending order, to give a unique id to each successive group of rows (0 values then 1) :

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, sum(invoiced) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date desc) grp
  FROM mytable
  ORDER BY ID, Date
)
SELECT ID, MAX(date) AS Date, MAX(Invoiced) AS Invoiced, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID, grp
ORDER BY ID, Date
```

Comment: Yes, I have tested it using your simple data https://dbfiddle.uk/RhfSh4dF, I get correct result

Comment: Very clever...you used descending date.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a combination of `LAG()` and `SUM()` as window functions, to create a pseudo group for each invoice period, for each `ID`:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(Invoiced, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) LagInvoiced
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(LagInvoiced) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) grp
    FROM cte1
)

SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Invoiced = 1 THEN Date END) AS InvDate,
    1 AS Invoiced,
    SUM(Amount)
FROM cte2
GROUP BY
    ID,
    grp
ORDER BY
    ID,
    InvDate;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's one with [correlated scalar subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fBfiPTS8)

```sql
select "ID", "Date", "Invoiced",
  (select sum(t2."Amount")+t1."Amount" 
   from my_table t2
   where t2."ID"=t1."ID"
     and t2."Invoiced"=0
     and t2."Date"<=t1."Date"
     and t2."Date">=(select coalesce(max("Date"),'0000-00') 
                     from my_table t3
                     where t3."ID"=t1."ID"
                       and t3."Invoiced"=1 
                       and t3."Date"<t1."Date")
  ) as "Amount"
from my_table as t1
where "Invoiced"=1;
```

| ID | Date | Invoiced | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2023-03 | 1 | 40 |
| AAA | 2023-06 | 1 | 30 |
| BBB | 2022-06 | 1 | 60 |
| BBB | 2022-08 | 1 | 60 |

To get more columns from the lookback, it would have to be moved down to `FROM` section as a [`LATERAL` subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) - works the same, but added columns make it no longer *scalar*, so it can't remain in the `SELECT` list.

[Here's a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78054343/5298879) where you can find a few performance tests comparing the two, in the comments. Long story short, window functions are simply the right tool for this task - less typing, higher performance. Still, alternatives are always worth a mention.